# Send SMS from laravel?

Tags: laravel, notify, sms-gateway

I have created a notification class called **Test**. When I called this class from here `$user->notify(new Test($user,$password,$message));` which method is called?.

I want to send SMS but inside that, it has a predefined method called

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
                    ->action('Notification Action', url('/'))
                    ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
    }
```

should I create another function for sending SMS? and how can I do that?

because I want to send an SMS to a URL something like this

```
$url='URL.php?USER=aaaa&PWD=bbbb&MASK=cccc&NUM='07453727272''&MSG='This is a message';
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your class there is a via method which is an array, returning, in your case. Mail. You may want to change that to 'nexmo' for example.

```
    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['nexmo'];
    }
```

> The via method receives a $notifiable instance, which will be an
>   instance of the class to which the notification is being sent. You may
>   use $notifiable to determine which channels the notification should be
>   delivered on:

Depending on the Gateway you are using for SMS there may be a specific notification which applies already: (see left hand navigation)

https://laravel-notification-channels.com/clickatell/

If you need a custom one, you should be able to follow the examples of some of the notifications channels already built to create your own. I'd add the specific SMS gateway you are using for clarity to see if I can provide additional information.